# Ease the handling of labels

Tags: cross-referencing, debugging, etoolbox

I want to ease the handling of labels in my document, and I want to show the label for a section if define a "variable".

Currently I'm doing it like this

Setting the up the "variable":

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{DEBUG}
\toggletrue{DEBUG}
%\togglefalse{DEBUG}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
\label{sec:NAT}
\iftoggle{DEBUG}{
    \subsubsection{Network Address Translation (NAT) [sec:NAT]}
}{
    \subsubsection{Network Address Translation (NAT)}
}
```

Is there an better way to do this? As it is now I still have to remember to set the same label in both places. Is there any libraries for this maybe?

I assume the best would be if there was a library that would allow me to write

```
\subsection{Section nam}{sec:NAT}
```

and then according to some setting it would output it correctly and also set the label!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: And remember that `\label` goes after `\<sub>section`. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper approach to this problem is to use a package written just for this purpose: `showlabels`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

Blah

\section{Start}\label{sec:start}

Blah

\subsection{Ready}\label{subsec:ready}

Blah

\subsection{Set}\label{subsec:set}

Blah

\subsection{Go}\label{subsec:go}

Blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

By just commenting out the `\usepackage{showlabels}` line, the labels won't be shown any more.

Comment: There is also a `final` option: "Finally, we have the options `final` and `draft`. The option `final` turns o all the functionality of this package. This is included so that if that option is given globally in the `\documentclass` declaration then this package does respect it. ..."

Comment: @krlmlr I prefer to comment out the package for preparing the final version of the document, because it patches some commands and some small risk of introducing break points or whatsits remains.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a wrapper command

```
\newcommand{\subsubsectionwithlabel}[2]{
    \iftoggle{DEBUG}{
        \subsubsection{#1 [#2]\label{#2}}
    }{
        \subsubsection{#1\label{#2}}
    }
}
```

and use that instead of `\subsubsection`:

```
\subsubsectionwithlabel{Network Address Translation (NAT)}{sec:NAT}
```

Comment: Hehe, was just about to post this myself as I figured it out myself, but you were faster. You got a tip for handling of \section \subsection \subsubsection? Or shall I just define one for each?

Comment: Define a "master" macro with three parameters (use the command as third parameter) and then define `\section` etc. as calls of that master macro.

Comment: Care to elaborate with an example?

Comment: `\newcommand{\withlabel}[3]{ ... #3{#1 [#2]} ... #3{#1} ...}` and then `\newcommand{\subsubsectionwithlabel}[2]{\withlabel{#1}{#2}{\subsubsection}}`.

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: Have you even tried `showlabels` as suggested by egreg? Indeed this seems more appropriate than your initial approach.

Comment: I have, and indeed it seems better, thats why I change that answer to the correct! :) But thanks anyway, you answer still got a "1 up".

Comment: This has the same problem as the example in @DavidEverlöf's question that the `\label` is in the wrong place, it needs to be after (or better in) the section argument not before.